# Can't access SwaggerUI in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, swagger

Recently I tried to add SwaggerUI to my REST application. I added needed dependencies and set up security config so my filter chain permits access to Swagger without authorization:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Lazy))
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Configuration
    public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

        @Bean
        public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
            CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
                    = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
            filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
            filter.setIncludePayload(true);
            filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
            filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
            filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA: ");
            return filter;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
               .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                 response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                 response.getWriter().write("Unauthorized 1.");
               })
                .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
                  response.getWriter().write("Unauthorized 2.");
                })
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(("/api/v1/auth/register")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I try to access http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html i got "Unauthorized 1." error. Is there something wrong with my configuration? Other endpoints that should work without auth are working well (for example, all endpoints for AuthController):

```
.requestMatchers(("/api/v1/auth/register")).permitAll() // works fine
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll() // gets 401 error
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
```